# Como cambiar el contenido de varios elementos con javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero cambiar el contenido de varios select barrio dependiendo del municipio escogido en otro select.

Esta es la forma en que lo hago con un solo select barrio

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function CargarBarrios(idSelBarrio, idMunicipio){
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/geo_location/barrio/consultar_barrios_por_municipio/'+idMunicipio,
                traditional: true,
                data: {
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                     var options = '<option value="">-Seleccione-</option>';
                     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                         options += '<option value="' + data[i][0] + '">' + data[i][1] + '</option>';
                     }
                     $("#"+idSelBarrio).html(options);
                 }
            });
       }
    </script>
```

Pero ahora necesito hacerlo con mas de un select barrio, todos contendrán la misma información.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: La información en los otros select será la misma o será diferente?

Comment: Es la misma en todos solos select

Comment: Si quisiera que fueran valores diferentes ¿como lo haría?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la información es la misma en todos los select entonces puedes usar un selector de clase en lugar de un selector de id.

```
$("."+idSelBarrio).html(options); //se cambia '#' por '.'
```

Y a todos los select les pones la misma clase, por ejemplo:

```
<select class="selectBarrioClass" name="select1"></select>
<select class="selectBarrioClass" name="select2"></select>
```